# Angular7 rewrite with apache not working correctly

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, angular7, apache2.4, angular7-router

I have my angular application `7.1.4` running on apache `2.4.10` server. I use `PathLocationStrategy` to route my urls.

Here is a glimpse at my index.html file

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
> <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
> <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
> <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
> <title>Intranet</title>
> <base href="/">
> ```

.htaccess file

> Options +FollowSymlinks
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
>
> RewriteRule ^ - [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]

The problem is, if my URL looks like

```
http://intranet.company.com/app/myspace?id=favorites
```

Apache redirects to

```
http://intranet.company.com/index.html?id=favorites
```

and my target page is not shown.

How can I solve this knowing that my URLs starts all with `BASE_URI/app/...`

Answer (score 0):

Remove / infront of index.html

```
   RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: Still the same issue.